# Upper bounds in search terms

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to find questions with say less than 3 answers or questions with no answer with score more than 2?

I have tried things like:

```
-answers:3
answers:-3
answers:<3
```

None of which have the desired effect.

If this is not currently supported, could it be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a upper bound you need to use `..X`, ie:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A..3 for questions with less than three answers.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A2..+answers%3A0 questions with score more than 1 and no answers.

Answer (score 1):

> less than 3 answers:

```
answers:0..2
```

> questions with no answer with score more than 2

A question with score more than 2 and no answers:

```
score:3.. answers:0
```